# VBA How to get all enum

Tags: vba, enums

I have an enum class in my VBA project:

```
Enum ruleEnum
    admins
    manager
    users
    supervisor
End Enum
```

Now, I want to get all enum values of this class and insert to a ComboBox. I want this to run dynamicly because I might put in new rules in the future. Who to get all rules in enum class to loop or collection

Comment: I dont think you can list your enumerations, i think you'll need to put them in a collection that you can access, like a dictionary maybe, google scripting.dictionary and then you can take the`.keys()` or `.items()` dependant on type from this collection and put it into the combo's `.list` property.

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/constants-enums/how-to-iterate-through-an-enumeration (you may need to adjust the language)

Comment: ^ as per @Nathan_Sav See also: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx and https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s386/enumerations.htm

Answer (score 5):

This article [Pearson Software Consulting:Enum Variable Type](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx) would have you use the underscore to define hidden Enumeration values to used in a loop like this:

> ```
> Enum ruleEnum
>     [_First] = 0
>     admins = 0
>     manager = 1
>     Users = 2
>     supervisor = 3
>     [_Last] = 3
> End Enum
> ```

But I think that we can do better.  Instead of assigning the first value of the loop at the beginning of the enumeration, I would assign it at the end.  In this way, we can define the beginning of the loop, `[_First]`, to equal the first enumeration value constant and the end of the loop , `[_Last]`, to equal the value of the last Enumeration constant that we want to loop over.

> ```
> Enum ruleEnum
>     admins
>     manager
>     Users
>     supervisor
>     [_First] = admins
>     [_Last] = supervisor
> End Enum
> ```

Alternatively you could write a function to return an Array of the enumeration values.

### Tests

```
Enum ruleEnum
    admins
    manager
    Users
    supervisor
    [_First] = admins
    [_Last] = supervisor
End Enum

Function getRuleEnumArray()
    getRuleEnumArray = Array(admins, manager, Users, supervisor)
End Function

Sub Tests()
    Dim n As Long

    For n = ruleEnum.[_First] To ruleEnum.[_Last]
        Debug.Print getRuleEnumArray(n), "Test: For n = [_First] To [_Last]"
    Next

    For n = LBound(getRuleEnumArray) To UBound(getRuleEnumArray)
        Debug.Print getRuleEnumArray(n), "Test: For n = LBound To UBound"
    Next

    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In getRuleEnumArray
        Debug.Print item, "Test: For Each"
    Next item

End Sub
```

### Results

[image]

Note: You can view the hidden members of an enumeration by Right Clicking the Object Browser and selecting Show Hidden Members.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this also (or use the above method to populate the dictionary, highlighting the dictionary use, not it's population)

```
Public dicEnums As Scripting.Dictionary

Public Sub set_enums()
    Set dicEnums = New Scripting.Dictionary
    dicEnums.Add "Admin", 1
    dicEnums.Add "Sales", 2
    dicEnums.Add "HR", 3
    dicEnums.Add "Production", 4
End Sub
```

Then this can be accessed like so

```
? dicEnums("Admin")
 1 
? join(dicEnums.Items(),"_")
1_2_3_4
? join(dicEnums.Keys(),"_")
Admin_Sales_HR_Production
```

or set the `.keys()` to `.list` of the combo

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

    If dicEnums Is Nothing Then
        set_enums
    Else
        If dicEnums.Count = 0 Then
            set_enums
        End If
    End If

    Me.ComboBox1.List = dicEnums.Keys()

End Sub
```